# I'm new to AS 3.0 programming and I am looking to create a randomizer for keyboard controls

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am trying to code for my coursework a random generator for controls, the game is a version of space invaders, but the game will include controls that are randomised every 10 seconds and it will change for 5 seconds. the code that I have

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent



    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
        var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
        var bullet 
        var myTimer:Timer = new Timer (10000, 90)
        //initaialises the variables by setting them to false

        public function Main() 
        {
            // constructor code
            Spaceship.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveToKey);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, whichKey);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, setKeyUnPres);
        }   //adds an evernt listener that will check for any key presses



        function whichKey(e:KeyboardEvent)
        {       // these are the key codes for the keys that will be pressed
                    // it also checks for if the key code is pressed 

            if (e.keyCode == 37)
            {       // that is left
                leftPressed = true;
                    // that sets the variable to true
                    //stating that it only has two conditions
                    // leads to a condition later, on line 54 
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 39)
            {       // that is right
                    // performss the exact same task as the one above
                    // leads to a condition later, on line 59
                rightPressed = true;
            }

                    // both of the funtions are triggered by pressing the 
                    //keys on your keyboard.
                    // the one above is triggered when you press the keys
                    //the one beneath is triggered when the key is pressed
        }

        function setKeyUnPres(e: KeyboardEvent)
        {       // function sets the variable to false, meaning that it doesn't activate
                //these functions are only trigged when the key is pressed down
            if (e.keyCode == 37)
            {       
                leftPressed = false;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 39)
            {
                rightPressed = false;
            }
        }

        function moveToKey (e:Event)
        {       // these function is run if both of the statements are run.

            // this is true for both conditions listed
            if (leftPressed && (Spaceship.x>0))
                // this function makes the Spaceship move 5 pixels to the left
            // when the variable leftPressed is true and the spaceship is greater than 0 pixels
            // the function will run
            {   
                Spaceship.x -= 5;

            }
            if (rightPressed && (Spaceship.x<550))
                // this function makes the Spaceship move 5 pixels to the right 
            // when the variable rightPressed is true and the shapscehip is less than 550 pixels
            // the function will run
            {
                Spaceship.x += 5;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 32) {
                var bulletshot:bullet = new bullet();
                addChild(bulletshot);
                bulletshot.x = Spaceship.x;
                bulletshot.y = Spaceship.y;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

that Is my code that I have so far, I need help on it as I am not entirely sure on how the code works for the randmomised function